# error: java.lang.NullPointerException in EditText when i try to setText string

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have an error: java.lang.NullPointerException in my EditText when i try to setText string.
I want to extract text from EditText to a Textview to insert into a database. I had a lot more code, but it was cutting up to find what the problem was.
Here is the codes:

```
package ccv.checkhellsing.guiapaa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class CrearUsuario extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText nombreUsuario;
String user;
Button flecha;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.crearusuario_layout);

    EditText nombreUsuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNombreUsuario);
    Button flecha = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btFlechaDerecha);

    flecha.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    user = nombreUsuario.getText().toString().trim();
}
}
```

---

And the Log:

```
06-23 17:20:59.605    2483-2483/ccv.checkhellsing.guiapaa      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL          EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ccv.checkhellsing.guiapaa.CrearUsuario.onClick(CrearUsuario.java:42)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9081)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I check my xml file and i sure that is not the problem.

Comment: Where is line 42 of `CrearUsuario.java`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `onCreate` you do

```
EditText nombreUsuario = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNombreUsuario);
```

This creates a new local variable named `nombreUsuario`, rather than assigning the value to your field `nombreUsuario` (which is what `onClick` references). Remove the `EditText` in front of it so that your `onCreate` sets the field's value.

(Similarly for your `Button flecha`)

Comment: Then this?

nombreUsuario = (EditarTexto) findViewById (R.id.etNombreUsuario) flecha = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btFlechaDerecha);

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't define Edittext and Button two times. Only global is enough.